# How to post ajax data in laravel 5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

This is my route file

```
Route::post('/ajaxdemo', 'DemoController@saveAjax');
```

This is my jquery ajax code

```
$('#record_form').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var select_form = $('#select_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajaxdemo',
        data: {
            mydata: select_form,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);

        }
    });
});
```

When im submitting the form the ajax request goes to a controller method

```
public function saveAjax(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->all();
   dd($data);

}
```

Im calling the ajax function from `/demo/create`, the page simply refreshes and displays the `token` in the `URL`. It does not display data even when im doing dd($data)

Comment: where is the e.preventdefault in the jquery method ?

Comment: @wahdan updated my question. please check

Comment: have you tried to pass in the url  $( '#record_form' ).attr( 'action' ); insted of '/ajaxdemo'

Comment: i have removed the action attribute of the form, but now it simply reloads current page and displays token in the URL

Comment: How come you're listening for the `'#record_form'` being submitted but then you're getting the data from `'#select_form'`?

Comment: can you add the action in the form using route helper function and get it in your jquery code and see the results

Comment: oh i didn't notice that you have record_form and select_form !!!, can you show your form?

Comment: actually i have 2 forms on the page and when second form's submit button is clicked i want to submit both form's data thats why there are 2 different form names

Comment: @wahdan it gives error: throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);

Comment: How come you're using 2 forms instead of 1?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var data = $('#record_form').val( );
            var formData=new FormData();
            formData.append('data',data);
                  $.ajax({
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                method: "POST",
                url:'{!! route('name of route') !!}',
                data: formData,
                success:function (e){alert('sucess')},
                error:function(e){alert('failed')}
            });
```

Comment: what is $('#data') ?

Comment: The record_form I mean.Editted

Comment: its simply reloading page and displaying token in url

Comment: Where did you write your route?in api.php or web.php?

Comment: in the web.php file

Comment: You should write    {{csrf_field()}}  in form and maybe in ajax...., because this code is for api

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      url:$("#select_form").attr('action'),
      dataType:'json',
      type:'POST',
      data:$("#select_form").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {}        
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want show data by ajax laravel.you can check data response or dd($data) by turn on inspect->network and run ajax again.You can see anything data or error

Maybe your request error 500 you can fix by https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf